# Resolve a AsyncStorage promise inside componenDidMount

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to check if a user is authenticated. I do this by checking some record in asyncStorage, I have the following code

App.js

```
let AuthService = require('./app/layouts/AuthService/AuthService.js');
export default class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        AuthService.getAuthInfo((err, authInfo) => {
            this.setState({
                checkingAuth: false,
                isLoggedIn: authInfo != null
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Auth.js

```
'use strict';

let AsyncStorage = require('react-native').AsyncStorage;
let _ = require('lodash');

const authKey = 'auth';
const userKey = 'user';

class AuthService {
    getAuthInfo(cb){
        AsyncStorage.multiGet([authKey, userKey], (err, val)=> {
            if(err){
                return cb(err);
            }
            if(!val){
                return cb();
            }
            let zippedObj = _.zipObject(val);
            if(!zippedObj[authKey]){
                return cb();
            }
            let authInfo = {
                header: {
                    Authorization: 'Basic ' + zippedObj[authKey]
                },
                user: JSON.parse(zippedObj[userKey])
            }
            return cb(null, authInfo);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = new AuthService();
```

In app.js, I'm trying to use this function from Auth.js, but I get no response from the fuction, I get console logs from getAuthInfo before I get into the AsyncStorage function. Im pretty new to react-native and ES6, and I think is a promise or async problem but I cant make it work. In app.js im redering a ActivityIndicator so I dont block the UI with checkingAuth and isLoggedIn.
I tried to use some .then in app.js with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you return your callback function instead of calling it. Try to call it by removing `return` like this : `cb(null, authInfo);`.